# C++: Random Number lists: x number of random integers

Tags: c++, for-loop, random, while-loop, integer

I am trying to write a program that generates and outputs x random integers num -- not yet using arrays or higher level C++ (I am in loops, such as while, for, etc.)

num is a random number between 20 to 50 and x is a random number between 10 to 15.

I also want to calculate and show the smallest, largest, sum, and average of those numbers.I expected my Sample test to output X number of random integers (in the case of the my failed sample run, it should be 12 random integers).

How do I make sure it displays all x integers and that each integer it displays in this list is random and unique, and not a repeat of the same random number (in my failed Sample Run at the bottom, this integer is 37, but I want it to be 12 different unique numbers)?

```
/*
OUTPUT SHOULD BE:
Generating 11 random numbers (11 is a random number between 10 to 15)...
...11 Random Numbers between 20 to 50:  26, 23, 48, 32, 44, 21, 32, 20, 49, 48, 34
Largest = 49
Smallest = 21
Sum = 377
Average = 377 / 11 = 34.3
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
     srand(time(NULL));
{
while (true){
        int sum = 0;
        int x = 10+rand()%6;
        int denom = x+1;
        int num = 20+rand()%31;
        int largest;
        int smallest;

        cout<<"Generating " << x << " random numbers (" << x << " is between 10 and 15)... \n";
        cout << "..." << x << " Random Numbers between 20 to 50: ";
        cout << num << endl;

        while(x >= 0)
        {
        largest = num;
        smallest = num;
        sum = sum + num;
        x--;
        }

        int average = sum / denom;

        cout << "Largest = " << largest << endl;
        cout << "Smallest = " << smallest << endl;
        cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
        cout << "Average = " << average << endl;

            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
}

/*
SAMPLE RUNS
==========
Generating 12 random numbers (12 is between 10 and 15)...
...12 Random Numbers between 20 to 50: 37
Largest = 37
Smallest = 37
Sum = 481
Average = 37

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.159 s
Press any key to continue.
*/
```

Comment: You should look into `<random>` library. Also, I think there is an issue with how you are seeding your random variable.

Comment: What happened with your last question? Deleting and re-asking questions isn't the way to avoid downvotes. Like I said, you're generating one random number and using it over and over again. Try [explaining your code to a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 1):

Use only one loop. Random number `num` should be generated within this loop.

It should be `while (x > 0){... x--;}` so for example if `x == 1` then the loop runs once. You can also use a `for` loop which is easier to understand.

`denom` is just saving the value for `x`. Therefore it should be `x`, not `x+1`

The values for `largest` and `smallest` should be initialized before the loop starts. Then you have to test the values.

I used zero to initialize `largest` and a very large value `RAND_MAX` to initialize `smallest`.

```
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int largest = 0;
    int smallest = RAND_MAX;
    int sum = 0;
    int x = 10 + rand() % 6;
    int denom = x;
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;

    while (x > 0)
    {
        int num = 20 + rand() % 31;
        cout << "num = " << num << endl;

        if(num > largest)
            largest = num;

        if(num < smallest)
            smallest = num;

        sum += num;

        x--;
    }

    cout << "Largest = " << largest << endl;
    cout << "Smallest = " << smallest << endl;
    cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Average = " << sum / denom << endl;
    return 0;
}
```